# PHP AJAX Live Search Page to target the same page instead of new window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way for this guide from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) to target the same page? Instead of opening a new window, it will just target the same page and open it there? As it is, it is opening an new page.

I checked on every possible solution, follow every solution provided in [daniweb](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/347660/xmlhttp-open-target-the-same-page) but still no luck.

I read the documentation [XMLHttpRequest.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) but there's nothing there that indicates a solution to the problem.

Your help would be much appreciated.

I tried the following for `xmlhttp.open("GET","backend/livesearch.php?q="+str,true);`

I modified the `.xml` link, so that it will follow the same format.

```
<link>
<title>Dashboard</title>
<url>/home.php</url>
</link>
```

And set it into the pathname.

```
<script>

var url = window.location.pathName;

function showResult_404(str) {
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("livesearch_404").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch_404").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch_404").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch_404").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url + "backend/livesearch.php?q=" + str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Is there a solution for this? The only reason why I'm doing this is because I'm running the Google Chrome page as an app via cmd `ChCp 65001` and `chrome --kiosk --app=""`, basically I am hiding the webpage and limiting user's accessibility, unfortunately this concern will become a vulnerability in the offline webpage that I'm doing as it will open a new window.

> EDIT: Problem solved by updating the `livesearch.php`

```
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_self'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_self'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Setting target to `target='_self`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your results in a anchor tag, example: Searched Results, this will be from a targeted page or db results.

Hope this helps

Comment: How will I approach this? may I ask for assistance?

Answer (score 1):

The form is still submitting so you should prevent it using:

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

in your form. You can also use event.preventDefault() in your js function if you want.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, it is still opening a new window.